# Setting CSV file lines reading limits

Tags: php, performance, csv, fgetcsv

I have a script that reads csv files and return them as an array. It reads many different files with different content, number of rows and columns and with different size (ex: from <1kb to >1Gb).

```
$data = [];
$file = fopen($file, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE  ) {
    $data[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
```

**I am looking for an elegant way to make sure that when it comes across large files it does not go over the whole file in order to avoid an excessive workload.**

Here are some ideas :

1. **Stopping after n rows.**
   However, for a large file that have few rows and several columns, that wouldn't help
2. **Read rows based on the size.** Ex: Read all the rows of a 500Mb file but only 50% of the rows of a 1Gb file. However, if the last rows are a bunch of empty rows or if they are more columns in the first rows, that solution wouldn't help.
3. **Monitor the size of `$data` and stop after a certain threshold.** I do not have any rational for excluding this idea except that I am not sure that it is a common way of doing things

Comment: I don't see any reason not to just stop when `$data` gets too large. The only reason it's not a common way of doing things is normally you want to read all the data regardless of how much there is.

Comment: @Chris Would you do it with `memory_get_usage()`?

Comment: Yes, that would seem a pretty reasonable way of doing it. It's probably also more efficient than keeping a count of the total bytes added to the array.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "excessive workload". Do you mean CPU load? That could be addressed via process control features and priorities. Execution time? That would call for a timeout solution. Memory consumption? etc.

Comment: @Guido I did not specify. I am not sure which one would be the bottle neck, I just want to make sure that one file one consume all the available resources.